# QEMU GPU passthrough on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, gpu, qemu

I am following a tutorial on how to run a VM that can use my [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit), and I have run into a problem.

Here are the tutorials:

- *[GPU pass through guide for Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-hOr44oBAI)*
- *[Multiheaded NVIDIA Gaming using Ubuntu 14.04 + KVM](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/)*

Here's my script for starting the VM:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

configfile=/etc/vfio-pci1.cfg

vfiobind() {
    dev="$1"
        vendor=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/vendor)
        device=$(cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/device)
        if [ -e /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver ]; then
                echo $dev > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver/unbind
        fi
        echo $vendor $device > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

}

modprobe vfio-pci

cat $configfile | while read line;do
    echo $line | grep ^# >/dev/null 2>&1 && continue
        vfiobind $line
done

sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -M q35 -m 8192 -cpu core2duo,kvm=off \
-smp 4,sockets=1,cores=2,threads=1 \
-bios /usr/share/seabios/bios.bin -vga none \
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 \
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi \
-drive file=/home/matthew/windows1.img,id=disk,format=raw, if=none -device scsi-hd,drive=disk \
-drive file=/home/matthew/Windows10.iso,id=isocd, if=none -device scsi-cd,drive=isocd \
-boot menu=on

exit 0
```

The error I get is:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/home/matthew/windows1.img,id=disk,format=raw,: drive with bus=0, unit=0 (index=0) exists
```

My PC hardware is:

- CPU: [Intel i5-4670](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i5_microprocessors#.22Haswell-DT.22_.28quad-core.2C_22_nm.29)
- Motherboard: ASrock H87M
- RAM: 16 GB Kingston
- HDD: Western Digital 500 GB
- SSD: Kingston 250 GB

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new img may help. Change it in your script.

See:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=windows#.img bs=1M seek=size count=0
```

where `windows#.img` is a unique name for each virtual machine image and size is the size of the image you want in GB * 1000. If you want roughly a 80 GB image, enter 80000. We want a 120 GB image, so we entered 120000. By default, this img file will be created in your `/home/user` folder.